# Implementing CTC without textImagegenerator in keras

Tags: image, keras, ocr, ctc

In keras/examples/image_ocr ctc loss was calculated using with TextImageGenrator which require monogram file and bigram file.
Can it be possible to feed only image and there ground truth values to calculate loss and predicting text?